# Reading a text file into c-string

Tags: c

I am working on a MediaPlayer project that will playback a text file instead of audio or video. My question is how do I display the string in the C-string array? For example, if in the text file I have (without quotes):

```
**"This is only test"**
```

and with my program I want to display it one word at a time like:

```
This
is
only
test
```

How do I do that? Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Global variables
int position=0; //to set the player position
float rate = 1.0; //the rate of playback

void LoadFile(const char *fileName, char *text){
    FILE *ifp; //a file pointer for file read/write

    //opening the file
    ifp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(ifp == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file \"%s\"!\n",fileName);
            exit(1);
    }
    else{
            fgets(text,50,ifp); //getting the text from the file
    }
    //closing the file  
    fclose(ifp); 
}

void *Start();
void *Stop();
void Rewind();
void SeekTo(int byteOffset);
void setRate(float rate);

int main(void){
    int i = 0;
    char choice;
    char fileName[25];
    char lineOfText[50];    //holds the text inside the file
    printf("Please enter the file you want to open: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    LoadFile(fileName,lineOfText);
    printf("%s",lineOfText);   //I will display the whole string

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have tagged your question "C++", why are you working with C functions and raw arrays?

Comment: `man perror`, `man strerror` for useful error messages.

Comment: You might want to retitle this question: it's not really about "how to read a text file into a string", but more "how do I enumerate over each word in a string".

Comment: Use std::ifstream, std::stringstream, std::cin, etc.  You're programming C and not C++.  If you look at examples of these it will become trivial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use strtok function

```
#include < stdio.h >

#include < string.h >

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  //printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

this code will give the output

```
This
a
sample
string
```

for further understanding go to the following

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok

Comment: The link doesn't work :(. Why do you split " ,.-" from NULL??

Comment: @EdwardFransindani - the correct link is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/.  As you can see from following this link, passing NULL in a second and subsequent call to `strtok` tells it to continue parsing the last string it was given.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C++ you can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) to easily do that. Once you read the line from the file you can construct a `string` and then use [`boost::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3184031):

```
string line(text);
vector<string> words;
split(words, line, is_any_of(" "));
```

After that, you can iterate through the `vector` obtaining the individual words you read from the file. For instance, for sequentially printing all the words (using C++11 syntax):

```
for (const auto& w : words)
    cout << w << endl;
```

Moreover, you may also want to consider porting your program to *real* C++. For that you would need to use `string` instead of a `char` array, use `ifstream` for reading the file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly reinventing the wheel, but damn useful on occasion:

```
// substring_container_adapter.h
//
// substring_container_adapter is useful for treating a single master string as a collection of substrings
// for the purpose of enumerating over those substrings (read-only)
//
// NOTES:
//  (1) sequential forward access is reasonably efficient, but random access is definitely not very efficient.  (bidirectional could be implemented)
//  (2) the strings must be valid for the lifetime of the adapter and any enumerators you obtain from the adapter
//  (3) uses a greedy algorithm - so whole sequences of delimiters are considered one separator, rather than multiple separators

namespace details 
{
    template <typename charT>
    class substring_container_adapter
    {
    public:
        struct iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, const charT *>
        {
            // iterator constructor
            iterator(const charT * pszPosition, const charT * pszDelimeters)
                : m_pszPosition(pszPosition)
                , m_pszDelimeters(pszDelimeters)
                , m_pszEnd(FindOneOfOrNil(pszPosition, pszDelimeters))
            { }

            // supported relational operators
            bool operator == (const iterator & rhs) const { return m_pszPosition == rhs.m_pszPosition; }
            bool operator != (const iterator & rhs) const { return m_pszPosition != rhs.m_pszPosition; }
            bool operator <  (const iterator & rhs) const { return m_pszPosition < rhs.m_pszPosition; }

            // increment to next substring
            iterator & operator ++ ()
            {
                const charT * pszNext = SkipDelimeters(m_pszEnd, m_pszDelimeters);
                if (pszNext)
                {
                    m_pszPosition = pszNext;
                    m_pszEnd = FindOneOfOrNil(m_pszPosition, m_pszDelimeters);
                }
                else
                {
                    m_pszPosition += GetLength(m_pszPosition);
                }

                return *this;
            }

            // postfix increment
            const iterator operator ++ (int)
            {
                // note: the const return type flags misuse patterns (see More Effective C++, Item 6)
                iterator old(*this);
                ++(*this);
                return old;
            }

            // dereference == CString
            CString operator * () const { return CString(m_pszPosition, static_cast<int>(m_pszEnd - m_pszPosition)); }

            // iterators on our characters
            const charT * begin() const { return m_pszPosition; }
            const charT * end() const { return m_pszEnd; }

        private:

            const charT *   m_pszPosition;
            const charT *   m_pszDelimeters;
            const charT *   m_pszEnd;
        };

        typedef iterator const_iterator;

    public:
        substring_container_adapter(const charT * pszString, const charT * pszDelimeters)
            : m_pszString(pszString)
            , m_pszDelimiters(pszDelimeters)
            , m_end(pszString + GetLength(pszString), m_pszDelimiters)
          { }

          // iterators
          iterator begin() const { return iterator(m_pszString, m_pszDelimiters); };
          iterator end()  const { return m_end; };

    private:
        const charT *   m_pszString;        // zero-terminated character array
        const charT *   m_pszDelimiters;    // delimiters
        const iterator  m_end;              // end delimiter
    };

}

typedef details::substring_container_adapter<TCHAR> substring_container_adapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error with:

```
printf("%s",lineOfText[0]);
```

is that the char uses a different flag.  You would need:

```
printf("%c",lineOfText[0]);
```

That would only print chars in the c-string.  Just iterate through the array to access the remaining chars.

Comment: should I use 2d array then to display a string in the array?I don't want to display it one character at a time but one whole word at a time.Thx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple hint,

- Take two variables. Initialize both of them with 0.
- Start traversing the string.
- If you find a space, note down the index of it into the second variable.
- Copy the contents from first variable declared to second variable into string.
- Make the first variable = second variable.

Keep doing the above steps until the string ends.